# Thousand separator on result

Tags: javascript, chart.js2

This script makes Chart.js add the data to the graph, so that it displays the data on the bar itself, but I would like to add the thousand separator and the currency symbol. I've got it to work with the currency symbol, but I'm not sure how to get the thousand separator.

```
animation: {
onComplete: function () {
    var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
    ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

    this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
            for(var key in dataset._meta)
            {
                var model = dataset._meta[key].data[i]._model;
                ctx.fillText("$ " + dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y - 5);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally worked it out by trial and error... Here's what I changed...

```
var model = dataset._meta[key].data[i]._model;
var salestotal = dataset.data[i];
if(parseInt(salestotal) >= 1000){
   salestotal2 = salestotal.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
} else {
  salestotal2 = salestotal;
}
ctx.fillText("$ " + salestotal2, model.x, model.y - 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many libraries (including d3) that help you format numbers but the browser also has a localised [one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) that works with currencies and even works on IE11.

```js
const number = 2350972467;

console.log(number.toLocaleString());

console.log(number.toLocaleString(navigator.language, { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var val = dataset.data[i].toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
ctx.fillText("$ " + val, model.x, model.y - 5)
```

Comment: I changed 2 lines to this: `var model = dataset._meta[key].data[i]._model;
                                            var salestotal = dataset.data[i];
                                            ctx.fillText("R " + salestotal.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","), model.x, model.y - 5);`. but it only worked on the first item of data. It didn't repeat it to the other items of data...